# Regular expressions in python (multiple variables)

Tags: python, regex

I have an array of strings that I want to match in python. Is there a way to do this without using for loops?

All the examples I have seen so far are like the following, where you have to loop through each element to find a match:

```
import re

patterns = [ 'this', 'that' ]
text = 'Does this text match the pattern?'

for pattern in patterns:
    print 'Looking for "%s" in "%s" ->' % (pattern, text),

    if re.search(pattern,  text):
        print 'found a match!'
    else:
        print 'no match'
```

Would it be possible to do this without using a for loop

Comment: What's wrong with using a for loop?

Comment: If text is one word, it means my answer is correct.If text is more than one word than its impossible to do it without for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the same as your for loop, but concatenate the patterns with a `|`. `a|b` matches if either `a` or `b` matches.

```
ultimate_pattern = '|'.join(patterns)
```

If you want to get all matches, use `findall`, but this way it cannot be known which original pattern triggered the match for it returns a list of strings.

```
re.findall(ultimate_pattern, text)
```

Comment: This is a very clever solution to the problem IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
import re

patterns = [ 'this', 'that' ]
text = 'Does this text match the pattern?'

if any(re.search(x, text) for x in patterns):
    print 'found a match!'
else:
    print 'no match'
```

It uses [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) to test every pattern in `patterns` against `text`.  As an added bonus, the solution uses lazy evaluation and will only test as many patterns as is necessary.

Comment: You used for loop.It must be without for loop.

Comment: No I didn't.  A for loop is what the OP has in their example.  I used a generator expression, which just happens to have the same `for` and `in` keywords.  Otherwise, what the OP wants is impossible since you need to iterate over the `patterns` list no matter what you do.  Even using `map` uses an implicit for-loop under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a while loop like so?

```
patterns = [ 'this', 'that' ]
text = 'Does this text match the pattern?'
test = True
position = 0

while test == True:
  if patterns[position] in text:
      print(patterns[position],'is in the text')

  else:
      print (patterns[position],'is not in text')

  position = position+1
  if position >= len(patterns):
      test = False
```

Answer (score 0):

import re

patterns = [ 'this', 'that' ]

text = 'Does this text match the pattern?'

def pattern_checker(patterns):

```
    pattern = iter(patterns)
    if re.search(next(pattern),  text):
            print 'found a match!'
            pattern_checker(pop_patterns(patterns))
    else:
            print 'no match'
            pattern_checker(pop_patterns(patterns))
```

def pop_patterns(patterns):

```
    if len(patterns) > 0:
            del patterns[0]
            return patterns
    else:
            return 0
```

try:

```
    pattern_checker(patterns)
```

except Exception, e:

```
    pass
```